# Failed to calculate the DC point error in Altium Simulation

Tags: simulation, altium, boost, spice

I'm new to simulations in Altium and I'm having a hard time diagnosing a simulation error. Hoping for some pointers. I've included images of the circuit and Altium output errors for references.

The design is a boost converter using TI's TPS40210DGQR with an external switch to boost a 24VDC signal to 48VDC at 2A.

While trying to run a DC sweep, I'm getting a number of single matrix errors on the net between Rg and the Gate of the FET M1 and then the simulation fails because it can't calculate the DC point. I read that on start up of the simulation, the simulation sees capacitors and inductors as open and therefore need a shunt resistor. The simulator seems to automatically add them. I also noticed it is adding one to pin 1 of the Resistor Rg. When I manually add a 100mOhm shunt resistor to ground between Rg and the input of the M1s gate, the simulation will execute however, the output of the simulation just shows 24V at the output. I added a probe to the gate and it measured 0V on the input of the gate, which confused me further.

I was wondering if anyone notices anything obviously wrong or if something in the setup of the simulator I'm missing.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Close up of M1]

[image: Simulation output]
[image: Schematic view]

Comment: Did you mean that you added 0.1 ohm between M1 gate and ground? If yes, this will make M1 permanently OFF and hence input supply will just reach the output via the inductor and diode. So, you'll get an output voltage slightly lower than 24V. The simulator does not add such a low value of shunt resistor. It will add a very high value shunt resistor.

Comment: Hi Sai, Thanks for the reply. No, the shunt resistor value I added (which is not pictured here) was 100mOhm, so very large, or are you reffering to the 11.3ohm resistor, Rg? Thanks

Comment: 100mOhm is 0.1Ohm isn't it?

Comment: Probably you intend to add 100E6 ohm. That will be 100MEG and not 100m.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still seeing 24v on the output of the simulation. I am going to look into the U1.x9.vma DC value 0 and u1.vm1 dc value 0 warnings that the compiler is also outputting. I could have the TI model improperly configured. I used the 'auto assign' feature inside the simulation dashboard to produce the simulation model for that

Comment: Yes, seems like you have other issues in your simulation as well

Comment: Thanks Sai, can you point them out?

Comment: I meant that since my suggestion did not fix the issue, you have other issues as well but I do not know exactly what issues you have in your simulation.